Can multipass clone an instance or launch a new instance from a snapshot
I have an instance with a snapshot at its perfect state.
I wonder if I can clone this instance so I can use it as a clean source of backup.
Or if I can launch a new instance using that snapshot for the same purpose.
Appreciate!
Ubuntu: 20.04 LTS
Multipass 1.14.0
Local OS: MacOSX 14.6.1

Please edit the question and add the version and type of Ubuntu you are using.
